# How to transfer cloth simulation from one mesh to another

Tags: animation, baking, cloth-simulation

I want to animate cloak for my character by using separate mesh(low poly).
[image]

And then apply to my cloak through deform modifier. Every thing is working.
But how can I bake this deformation modifier with simulation into my actual model?
[image]
Video:
https://youtu.be/V-3TPf8ql0M

Comment: Why do you want to "bake" modifier? That is your goal?

Comment: I want to export full animated character into another soft. To be more precise, the site - sketchfab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was much easier than i thought. I used mdd and everything worked.

if anyone is interested here is the link:
https://youtu.be/AEP2RgaBGlk

Answer (score 0):

Then preparing animation to an external software for you have to know, that end platform can support. According to [documentation](https://help.sketchfab.com/hc/en-us/articles/203058018-Animations#uploading), sketchfab can play only this type of animations:

> Solid animation: translation, scale, rotation
>
> Skeleton-based
> animation: model rigged with bones
>
> Morph targets: transformed vertices
> (Shape keys)

As you see, it can't play Blender's modifiers nor Blender cloth (and others) simulation.

Also in the documentation you can see, that it supports [Timeframe (Stop Motion)](https://help.sketchfab.com/hc/en-us/articles/203058018-Animations#timeframe) animation. In this case, you can export animation into OBJ sequence:

[image]

And use the [workflow described here](https://help.sketchfab.com/hc/en-us/articles/203058018-Animations#timeframe)

Comment: May be somebody know more accurate or effective method of animating it. My problem, why I won't use cloth sim directly on the model, is that it has thickness